# When reading in file, and use nextLine() to move to the next line, it causes the read in to skip every other line

Tags: java

```
try {
        FileReader in = new FileReader("generibrand.txt");
        input = new Scanner(in).useDelimiter(":");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFound) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No File Found!");
    }
    try {
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String drugClass = input.next();
            if (drugClass.equals("ab")) {
                meds = new Antibiotic(input.next(), input.next(), input.next());
                medList.add(meds);
            } else if (drugClass.equals("av")) {
                System.out.println(drugClass);
                meds = new Antiviral(input.next(), input.next(), input.next());
                medList.add(meds);
            } else if (drugClass.equals("ur")) {
                meds = new UrinaryAntiInfective(input.next(), input.next(), input.next());
                medList.add(meds);
            } else if (drugClass.equals("ps")) {
                meds = new Parasympathomimetic(input.next(), input.next(), input.next());
                medList.add(meds);
            } else if (drugClass.equals("sa")) {
                meds = new Sympathomimetic(input.next(), input.next(), input.next());
                medList.add(meds);
            } else if (drugClass.equals("no")) {
                meds = new Opiate(input.next(), input.next(), input.next());
                medList.add(meds);
            } else if (drugClass.equals("ad")) {
                meds = new Antidepressant(input.next(), input.next(), input.next());
                medList.add(meds);
            } else if (drugClass.equals("du")) {
                meds = new Diuretic(input.next(), input.next(), input.next());
                medList.add(meds);
            } else if (drugClass.equals("db")) {
                meds = new Diabetic(input.next(), input.next(), input.next());
                medList.add(meds);
            } else if (drugClass.equals("cs")) {
                meds = new CNSStimulant(input.next(), input.next(), input.next());
                medList.add(meds);
            } else if (drugClass.equals("cd")) {
                meds = new Cardiac(input.next(), input.next(), input.next());
                System.out.println(meds.getBrandName() + ((Cardiac) meds).getCategory());
                medList.add(meds);
            } else if (input.hasNextLine()) {
                input.nextLine();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something Went Wrong!");
    }
```

I have tried numerous tests to see what exactly was being displayed... The most confusing part for me is if I stick in a `System.out.println(drugClass);` at the beginning before all the IF statements it will print out each of the words line after line, and print ALL of them. But when I take out that print line, and refrain from using `input.nextLine()` to move to the next line in the text file, it only enters the first if statement, and my ArrayList of meds does not get populated. When I DO use `input.nextLine()` in my code it skips every other line when iterating through the file...

Fairly confused how I am getting such odd results, anyone have any idea of why this is occuring? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would highly suggest restructuring your program. Instead of using a bunch of `if`s, place all of the drug classes into an `enum` with `String` and `Class` fields.

Comment: Do you think the problem lies within my code structure and changing it would avert from any potential issues (the one that im having)?

Comment: It would avoid code duplication which would lead to less chances of introducing elusive bugs through typos.

Comment: I would question your object model. Do you really need all these drug-class classes? Normally inheritance is only used for imaginary computing objects like connections, not for real-world objects. Apart from teaching examples like Animal/DogCat, you never see this sort of thing in real code. What happens if they come up with another drug class? Is there really anything different about the various drug-class classes? I would just have a single DrugClass class, with a name property and three other properties for whatever you're reading  from the file. The n all this reduces to about five lines.

Comment: Yes, when I was making the classes it was purely to demonstrate what has been the emphasis during this years school semester. If I wasn't concerned if I had the marks I would have kept them all as simply Medication objects. I found the issue, it was within my generibrand.txt file I needed to add delimeters at the end of each line. I discovered this upon close analysis of the `System.out.println();` of each line, and noticed every other line it was breaking early and going to the next line. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, I had not properly set up the delimeters in the file, and noticed the issue by printing out each line and spotting out odd print outs and determined from that, that it was skipping a line due to the delimeters. I feel like I am rather poorly explaining it. At the same time though having the duplicate `while(input.hasNextLine()){if(input.hasNextLine(){input.nextLine()}}`